# Find intersection among a single Array's elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
[".a",".acc",".as",".b",".bad",".ca",".cat"]
```

These array elements are supposed to be searched in a long string.

```
fire consumed his plane. AAC was required to have two persons. A third employee who was present at the airport. As a result, Richard was unable to escape
```

So when it searches for `".acc"` it finds only one result. But when it searches for `".a"` it finds three results. Now the results are repeating, which is making trouble.

I want some way to remove elements `".acc"` and `".as"` from this array and keep `"a"` in the array, so that I can search only for `".a"`

It is some sort of intersection among the elements of an array. but I can't figure out a straight forward solution to this issue.

Summery: I have got three items in an array with same starting characters(.a) . I want to keep the item with lowest length and remove the other two.

Comment: It is quite unclear what are you actually trying to achieve. Can you be more specific, or give an example or a desired result?

Comment: I have got three items in an array with same starting characters(.a) . I want to keep the item with lowest length and remove the other two.

Comment: @Iqbal You should edit the question to include that phrase - it clarifies things much better. Additionally, you should include your code/attempts, rather than just asking us to write it for you :)

Comment: Why not use a regex with [**word boundaries**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fill `z` with the non-overlapping strings from the original array:

```
let z = [];
let cur;
['.a', '.acc', '.as', '.b', '.bad', '.ca', '.cat'].sort().forEach((x) => {
  if (!x.startsWith(cur)) {
      z.push(x);
      cur = x
  }
})
```

(The `sort()` call is only needed if the original array may not always be already sorted.)

Comment: I believe he wants to remove the overlapping results of searching with those strings not the strings themselves.

Comment: Even so, generating a new array does not change the original array. And he can just pass the new array to the existing method.

Comment: No, no, that's not what I meant. What I was trying to say is that OP uses the strings in the array to search for matches in another string. Giving that `.a` is more generalized than `.acc` and `.as`, the results of both `.acc` and `.as` are included in the result array of `.a`. OP wants `.a` results to be just those of `.a`, not those of `.acc` and `.as`.

Comment: I see what you are saying, now. But it is not clear to me that is what OP is asking for. Can @Iqbal clarify whether the above comment is correct?

Comment: @cybersam He said this in the comments: *"I have got three items in an array with same starting characters (`.a`) . I want to keep the item with lowest length and remove the other two."* I suggested he add this to the question itself but it seems that's yet to happen - may edit it myself as it seems to drastically clarify the question.

Comment: Hey @cybersam. Your code does exactly what I need. Thank You so much

Answer (score 2):

USe [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate the array. Use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that the element doesn't [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) all other element (except itself).

```js
const arr = [".a",".acc",".as",".b",".bad",".ca",".cat"];

const result = arr.filter(s1 => 
  arr.every(s2 => 
    s1 === s2 || !s1.startsWith(s2)
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

ES5 version:

```js
var arr = [".a",".acc",".as",".b",".bad",".ca",".cat"];

var result = arr.filter(function(s1) {
  return arr.every(function(s2) {
    return s1 === s2 || !s1.startsWith(s2);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey Ori, Thans for the answer. You code do exactly what I need. There is just one little problem. The code syntax is not supported on IE. and the code is to be run on IE.

Comment: @Iqbal This answers the question you've asked - you originally made no mention of IE. Perhaps Ori Drori will be nice enough to do you a favor and convert the arrow functions to basic functions, however at this point I'd say the onus is on you to do the 5 minutes of research and convert it to an IE friendly version. Simply change `s1 => array.every...` to `function (s1) { return array.every...`, and change `s2 => s1 === ...` to `function (s2) { return s1 === ...`

Comment: @Iqbal - I've added an ES5 version.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inputString = ".a .as .as .acc .acc .acc REST OF STRING...";

let keywords = [".a", ".acc", ".as", ".b", ".bad", ".ca", ".cat"];

function getOccurrenceOfKeyword(searchString, keyword) {
  return searchString.split(keyword).length - 1;
}

function matchingKeywordsOccurrence(searchString, searchKeyword) {
  let matchingKeywordsOccurrence = 0;
  keywords.forEach(keyword => {
    if (keyword.startsWith(searchKeyword) && keyword !== searchKeyword) {
      matchingKeywordsOccurrence += getOccurrenceOfKeyword(
        searchString,
        keyword
      );
    }
  });
  return matchingKeywordsOccurrence;
}

function findExclusiveOccurrenceOfKeyword(searchString, searchKeyword) {
  let keywordOccurrence = getOccurrenceOfKeyword(searchString, searchKeyword);
  return (
    keywordOccurrence - matchingKeywordsOccurrence(searchString, searchKeyword)
  );
}

console.log(findExclusiveOccurrenceOfKeyword(inputString, ".a"));
console.log(findExclusiveOccurrenceOfKeyword(inputString, ".as"));
console.log(findExclusiveOccurrenceOfKeyword(inputString, ".acc"));
```